# Passing a tuple for plotting in matplotlib throws a "Tuple Object is not callable" error at line no. 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

[image: Please find the output below]I am plotting a graph using matplotlib but python is throwing an error 'Tuple is not callable'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax[0, 0].plot(range(10), 'r')
ax[1, 0].plot(range(10), 'b')
ax[0, 1].plot(range(10), 'g')
ax[1, 1].plot(range(10), 'k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you copy the full error please?

Comment: The code that is shown in the question is correct and does not produce any error. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your python version because range() function works different in python 2 and python 3